# How to properly read a text file?

Tags: io, rust

rust-0.11

newbie question:

```
fn main() {                                                                    
    use std::io::File;                                                         
    use std::str;                                                              

    let unwrapped_data = match File::open(&Path::new("/proc/net/dev")).read_to_end() {
        Ok(byte_mas) => byte_mas,                                              
        Err(why) => fail!("couldn't open: {}", why.desc),                      
    };                                                                         

    println!("{}", str::from_utf8_owned(unwrapped_data));                      
}
```

output:

```
./netstat
Ok(Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 1534066   17270    0    0    0     0          0         0  1534066   17270    0    0    0     0       0          0
enp2s0: 251195693  592728    0 17723    0     0          0         0 43664332  107083    0    0    0     0       0          0
)
```

How to read without 'Ok()'?
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details

Comment: (Did you mean to have 'details' repeated many times without actually providing any more details?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`from_utf8_owned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/std/str/fn.from_utf8_owned.html) has signature:

```
pub fn from_utf8_owned(vv: Vec<u8>) -> Result<String, Vec<u8>>
```

That is, it takes a vector of bytes, and returns a string (if the bytes are a valid utf8 sequence) or the original vector (if they are not), hence you have to handle this possible error. One possibility would be:

```
match str::from_utf8_owned(unwrapped_data) {
    Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
    Err(_) => fail!("file was not valid UTF-8")
}
```

The reason the code you have "works" is `Result` implements the `Show` trait (which is what the `{}` formatter calls), and so it can be printed directly.

(You can actually abbreviate this process via [`Reader.read_to_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/std/io/trait.Reader.html#method.read_to_str), which reads the whole reader and checks if it is UTF-8 or not internally.)